# Increase hexadecimal places

Tags: kotlin, type-conversion, byte

I'm trying to increase the number of places a hexadecimal is using.
I've managed to do this when I'm using String, by using `String.format("%04X", bytes)`.

But my source is of `ByteArray` and I would like to avoid partially converting it to String, change the number of places and then convert it back into bytes.

So the idea is in my source I have something like this `0D` which I want to be `000D` in my final representation. But I want to achieve this before fully converting my source to hex representation.

Is there a more direct way to achieve this?

Comment: How can you know where the boundaries between numbers are if they have variable length in bytes?

Comment: In my case this should always be sent with 2 bytes (and prepend if needed), but my input accepts the format with only 1 byte. I'm using TLV for this which uses a single byte for the length.
For now I've converted everything to String, made the change and converted everything back to binary. But was wondering if it is a way to do it in binary directly.

Comment: So my end result should be similar with `String.format("%04d", bytes)` which will return `0013` for my case.

Comment: You talk about expanding one byte to two bytes, but a single hexadecimal digit already represents four bytes. So do you actually want to expand 8 bytes to 16 bytes? Or do you want to expand one byte to 16 bytes by adding a bunch of 0s in front of each input byte?

Comment: I think my explanation was a little off. I just want something like this "13" to become "0013". I could have something like "1750" which will end up as "1750". In my hex representation one hex occupies 2 chars. When I'm converting this to binary this ends up with half the size as each binary represents a hex that was occupying 2 spaces. If my number is only 2 digits only it will end up messing up my total length, thus I need to represent it with 2 bytes, even though one of them will be a 0 in case of "13" for example.

Comment: That brings me back to my first question about number boundaries. How do you know whether you’re looking at a number that needs zeroes added to the front vs the first two digits of a longer number? 13 might need zeroes added in front of it, or it could be part of a bigger number that starts with 13.

Comment: This is being part of a TLV(tag-length-value) object that can be extracted accordingly. I just need to convert that length to a different format. 
Like I said, I did it already, but I needed to convert it to string, change it, convert it back to binary. 
My question is if I could do it directly in binary. To avoid converting it to string and back again.

Comment: Wait, does the ByteArray consist of a single number? I've been assuming the whole time that it is a series of a bunch of numbers so that's why I keep asking about number boundaries.

Comment: It contains multiple values, but this being in TLV format I can pinpoint what is the index for my number. 
I could even break it down and extract the value separately and after that recreate it, but from a performance point of view I think I will end up with something similar to what I have now.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TLV, but it seems you just need to allocate a new ByteArray with the correct length for all your numbers to fit. It is allocated with all zeroes, so then you just need to transfer each number from the original ByteArray to the right position, and there will be zeroes filling in front of each number.